# Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Tags: php

I've read alot on other forums, they said that the error was that there was whitespace before the session_start but I'm extremely sure there isnt, my file is encoded in UTF8 without BOM so that white-space problem should be fine and it's working perfectly on local (I'm using easyphp)... Still, as soon as I put it online, it pops me those problem... anyone can help? They're telling those two lines of error online :

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this on the top just after `<?php`

```
ob_start();
```

you can use like this:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

include 'your php file';

...
...
```

Comment: It removed one error but it doesnt seem to work completely, is that because i use :

<?php include(functions.php) ?>

And I use the session_start() in the file functions... can it be the problem ?

Comment: please look at the updated answer